# Replace null features with features from other field

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator

I have a polygon shapefile with two fields X and Y. I'd like to create a new field Z reporting the feature/value of X when Y is missing, and the feature of Y otherwise. The function in QGIS Field Calculator would be `if(Y IS NULL, X, Y)`. I'd like to find a way to write it in a PyQGIS code.

On PyQGIS I've attempted:

```
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(my_dir, "my_layer", "ogr")

my_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Z", QVariant.String)])
my_layer.updateFields()

with edit(my_layer):
    for f in my_layer.getFeatures():
        if f["Y"] == NULL:
            my_layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), my_layer.fields().lookupField("Z"), f["X"])
            my_layer.updateFeature(f)
        else:
            my_layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), my_layer.fields().lookupField("Z"), f["Y"])
            my_layer.updateFeature(f)
```

but it does not work. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: What if both or none is missing?

Comment: Is PYQGIS mandatory ?

Comment: Did you try `f["Y"] is None` instead of `f["Y"] == NULL` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the expression you already use through the GUI but with PyQGIS

```py
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(my_dir, "my_layer", "ogr")
#my_layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Add if not existing
if my_layer.fields().indexFromName('Z') == -1:
    my_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Z", QVariant.String)])
    my_layer.updateFields()

expression = QgsExpression('coalesce(Y, X)')
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(my_layer))

with edit(my_layer):
    for f in my_layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['Z'] = expression.evaluate(context)
        my_layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0]
zindex = lyr.fields().indexFromName('Z')
attrMap = {}

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    vals = [f['X'],f['Y']]
    if None in vals: #If there are no Nones, dont set a value for Z.
        z = [v for v in vals if v][0] #"if v", is True for values that are not None or empty strings
        attrMap[f.id()] = {zindex:z}
#attrMap
#{1: {2: 'abc'}, 2: {2: '123'}}

lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the question properly. "If there are no Nones, dont set a value for Z." --> Nope, the question says Z should be always set. So, even if X and Y are not None, Z should get the Y value. Also, if the pair [X,Y] is [0, None], you should pick 0, but `z = [v for v in vals if v][0]` won't do that.